# Cannot connect to mongodb using machine ip

Tags: mongodb

Installed `Mongo` using `homebrew`. If I type `mongo` on shell, it gets connected to `test`. But when I type the `ip address` of the local machine instead of `127.0.0.1`

```
mongo --host 192.168.1.100 --verbose
```

It gives me error message

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
Fri Aug 23 15:18:27.552 versionArrayTest passed
connecting to: 192.168.1.100:27017/test
Fri Aug 23 15:18:27.579 creating new connection to:192.168.1.100:27017 
Fri Aug 23 15:18:27.579 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Fri Aug 23 15:18:27.580 Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.1.100:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
Fri Aug 23 15:18:27.580 User Assertion: 12513:connect failed
```

Have tried modifying the `mongo.conf` by commenting `bind_ip` or by changing the ip address from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` but no luck. This should be simple but have no clue now. Using mac.

Thanks

Update: As requested. This works after I have made the changes as you suggested.

ifconfig output

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
   options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
   inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
   inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
   inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
   options=b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING>
   ether XX:XX:XX:
   media: autoselect (none)
   status: inactive
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
   ether XX:XX:XX:XX:01 
   inet6 XXXX:XXXX:XXXX: %en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
   inet 192.168.1.100 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
   media: autoselect
   status: active
 p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
   ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   media: autoselect
   status: inactive
 fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
   lladdr XX:XX:XX:XX
   media: autoselect <full-duplex>
   status: inactive
```

Output when executing command `mongo --host 192.168.1.100 --verbose`

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
Fri Aug 23 16:42:09.806 versionArrayTest passed
connecting to: 192.168.1.100:27017/test
Fri Aug 23 16:42:09.837 creating new connection to:192.168.1.100:27017
Fri Aug 23 16:42:09.837 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Fri Aug 23 16:42:10.129 connected connection!
Server has startup warnings: 
Fri Aug 23 16:41:59.025 [initandlisten] 
Fri Aug 23 16:41:59.025 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
```

File `mongod.conf`

```
# Store data in /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db
dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb

# Append logs to /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logpath = /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logappend = true

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0`
```

Comment: Firewall issues would be my first guess.  Don't know Macs so I can't really direct you further.

Comment: I have tried with `no firewall` on mac and on same machine. I can ping myself using the ip but cannot connect over mongo.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just tested this on my Mac with Homebrew, works fine *if* you change the bind address. I suspect you probably just didn't get the config for bind correct?

Just so we have all the information, can you paste the output of `ifconfig` please?

By default, MongoDB should listen on all interfaces, you shouldn't need to change the configuration, however, the Homebrew setup seems to override this (/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf):

```
# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Please kill MongoDB and run this (note the -v):

```
$ mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 -v
warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

Just paste your output for that please?

And then just try:

```
$ mongo --host 192.168.43.2 --verbose
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
Sat Aug 24 09:07:14.556 versionArrayTest passed
connecting to: 192.168.43.2:27017/test
Sat Aug 24 09:07:14.657 creating new connection to:192.168.43.2:27017
Sat Aug 24 09:07:14.657 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Sat Aug 24 09:07:14.657 connected connection!
Server has startup warnings: 
Sat Aug 24 09:06:44.360 [initandlisten] 
Sat Aug 24 09:06:44.360 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files     is 256, should be at least 1000
>
```

Obviously replace it with your IP address. Let us know how that goes.

Comment: But I still don`t get it. Why this did not work when I modified `mongo.conf` file to accept `bind_ip 0.0.0.0`

Comment: @java_dude Hmm, that does sound weird. Can you check your `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` file?

Comment: What should I look for in the log file? BTW, updated question with `mongod.conf` content

Comment: @java_dude I just noticed (and this may just be a typo) that your "bind_ip" line ends not with a "0", but with a tick mark "`"... if this was a direct copy/paste I would guess that would be the issue

Comment: If mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 -v fails then specify the path where you want your data and then run the command mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 -v -dbpath "<data path>"

Answer (score 8):

success:

1. change service config file C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg

```
# network interfaces (wjp: comment bindIp listening on all IPs)
net:
  port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

2. restart mongodb service (or restart computer);
3. make sure machine level firewall open port 27017
4. connect ok.

Answer (score 3):

No
In fact, if you want to access the rest interface from any ip, you needn't set bind_ip to 0.0.0.0 in the mongod.conf, you only comment or remove the configuration item from it, as similar as

```
#bind_ip=127.0.0.1
```

And then, restart your service, you can find that you can access the rest service from the 28017 port from your machine

Comment: this is a bad practise!

Comment: This worked. I used it to bind it to my internal server network address, instead of commenting it out, and used a external firewall to expose it to authorized IP addresses. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For me I replaced the bindIp with bindIpAll: true (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/ for details).

This is the content of my mongod.conf file.

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  # bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  bindIpAll: true


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Below configuration is for windows 10 & MongoDB 4.0**

There are two ways to configure this.

1. Using shell commands.
2. Or through `mongod.cfg`.

**Using shell commands**

First open the `cmd` as `administrator` and go to `--YourPath--\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin`

1. If you already running the MongoDB service then run this command or else, go to second point.`mongod --remove`
2. Then set the path for data folder, log file and ip bind using the below command

   `mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data" --logpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongod.log" --bind_ip "0.0.0.0" --install --serviceName "MongoDB"`

**caution: This ip configuration gives access to your DB throughout the network.**

3. Now go to `services.msc` and find the `MongoDB`, then **Right click -> Start** the service.

**Through `mongod.cfg`**

MongoDB has a very good documentation for [Configuration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file) here.

Just change the `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` to `bindIp: 0.0.0.0`. Then restart the service using the #3 point from the above topic.