# nodejs application - mongodb connection fails with error "ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

**Background Information**

I'm playing around with my first nodejs test app that is attempting to connect to a remote mongodb.

**Problem:**

The connection is failing with the following message:

```
admin@testdev:~/Documents/nodejs_tests$ sudo nodejs index.js
Server has started.
Request for / received
About to route a request for: /
inside db connect method
Request for /favicon.ico received
About to route a request for: /favicon.ico
inside db connect method
MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED
null
MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED
null
```

Here's the logic to connect:

```
function connect_nimble() {
        console.log("inside db connect method");
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://10.1.1.1:27017/test", function(err,db) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(db);
                if(!err) {
                        console.log("booya!  Connected to mongo");
                        return true;
                }
        });
}
```

**What I've checked so far:**

1. I've made sure that the database server is using port 27017.  Here's what I see in the mongodb logs when i restart the database:

   ```
   admin@mongotest:~$ tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log 
   2015-07-21T09:52:41.452-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
   2015-07-21T09:52:41.452-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
   2015-07-21T09:52:41.452-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
   2015-07-21T09:52:41.452-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.4
   2015-07-21T09:52:41.452-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5
   2015-07-21T09:52:41.452-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
   2015-07-21T09:52:41.452-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info:  Linux ip-10-45-73-23 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
   2015-07-21T09:52:41.452-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
   2015-07-21T09:52:41.452-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
   **2015-07-21T09:52:41.470-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017**
   ```
2. I've made sure I have a database called "test" by starting "mongo"... and then switching in and out of the test database using the "use test" / "use admin" commands.
3. I don't believe I have authorization turned on.  This is what I have in the mongo.conf file:

> ```
> # Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
> #noauth = true
> #auth = true
> ```

And to prove it, in order to get into the test database on the server via command line, I just have to type "mongo" and then by default, I'm in the test database.  So I think I can safely assume I don't have any authentication going on.

4. Just in case, I also checked netstat for the port number:

   admin@mongotest:~$ sudo netstat -taupen | grep mongo
   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      117        6465150     18792mongod
   admin@mongotest:~$

I'm currently reading the manual to see if there's anything else I should be checking.  I'm also reading through the various stackoverflow posts that are similar, but I haven't found me an answer yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your netstat output clearly shows mongod is listening on only 127.0.0.1 interface. You need to change your connect string to mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test.

Comment: see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37994794/3166417

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see in your logs that Mongo is listening on 127.0.0.1.  This is likely your problem.  You will have to change the bind-ip address configuration setting to allow Mongo to listen to specific or all IP addresses.  You can find how to do this here:  [Cannot connect to mongodb using machine ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412850/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-using-machine-ip)

Comment: Or, as one of the comments suggests, if your Node service is running on the same machine as Mongo, change your connection string to localhost: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal.

Type `mongod &` and check the stacktrace.

This is an example of a failing start

`I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting`

To fix this, Create the folder /data/db

In the terminal, type `mkdir /data/db`

Type again`mongod`

It works !!

`[initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000`