# Why is my mongod.conf file being ignored?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Followup from both [Can't connect to MongoDB server on Google Compute Engine from second VM instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347401/cant-connect-to-mongodb-server-on-google-compute-engine-from-second-vm-instance/37371979#37371979) and [Cannot connect to mongodb using machine ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412850/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-using-machine-ip) .

Editing mongod.conf to change to `bind_ip=0.0.0.0` (or any other address) fails to be picked up and mongo will only listen to 127.0.0.1.

However, if I `systemctl stop mongodb.service` and then `mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0` (or any safer address) then it runs just fine and my remote instances are able to connect.

Why does this happen, and more practically.. how can I get my Ubuntu to do this on boot without me having to manually start up mongo?