# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Security Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have a web application launched using ElasticBeanstalk (EB) with load balancer, which instances may be added/removed based on the trigger.
Now I have a Redis server hosted on EC2 with port 6379 that I only want this very EB instances (all the instances launched by this EB) have access to that port.
EB has a security group (SG) called `sg-eb` and Redis has a SG called `sg-redis`.

All these are deployed under same VPC but may or may not be the same subnet.

How to I configure `sg-redis` so that all the instances under the EB have access to redis? I tried adding `sg-eb` to `sg-redis` allowing port 6379 but no luck. The only way I made it work was adding each instance's public IP to `sg-redis` so they have access. Though, if the load balancer adds/removes an instance, I'll need to manually configure `sg-redis` again.

**Update #1**
[image]

Comment: can you maybe share some pictures of your setup so we can help? What you mentioned so far should work, theoretically :)

Comment: "I tried adding sg-eb to sg-redis allowing port 6379 but no luck" that's all you should have to do in the security group. Make sure the EB servers are referencing the EC2 Redis server via its private IP address.

Comment: is the EB environment and the redis box inside the same VPC?

Comment: @mostafazh please see updated image.

Comment: @MarkB can you please describe more on what you mean by "EB servers are referencing the EC2 Redis server via its private IP address"? How do I setup by that way?

Comment: @eugecm yes they are

Comment: The redis ec2 instance will have 2 ips, one public and one private. You can find them when selecting the instance on the ec2 management console. Make sure you connect to that ec2 instance via this internal ip

Comment: @mostafazh awesome, got it working. By any chance you know how I can use the same logic for DB server (eg. MongoDB)? I have similar setup but when I try to connect, MongoDB always says authentication failed by connecting to the private IP of the instance.

Comment: @lancelot see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redis EC2 instance will have 2 IPs, one public and one private. You can find them when selecting the instance on the EC2 management console. Make sure you connect to that EC2 instance via this internal IP.

Comment: @lancelot would mongodb accept the connections if tried to connecting to public IPs? Make sure mongodb server is not listening (binded) to the localhost, but rather to all network interfaces. You come find more about mongodb configurations here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413175

Comment: yeah, it's not listening to locolhost and connecting using public IP works. It's the private IP not working with error saying "Authentication failed"

Comment: That doesn't look like an security group issue, if mongodb is replying with with an authentication failed. My suggestion is to post a new question for this issue AFTER you confirm there is nothing wrong with the user password or other silly issues like that 