# Can't connect mongoDB server

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-boot, tcp

I try to use springboot to connect mongoDB server, and I set some properties in file `application.properties` 
like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=crinews
spring.data.mongodb.username=yichen
spring.data.mongodb.password=123456
```

Everything is ok. But when I modify the properties like:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.2.63
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=crinews
spring.data.mongodb.username=yichen
spring.data.mongodb.password=123456
```

I just modify `spring.data.mongodb.host` and got the exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:477) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:228) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveReply(CommandHelper.java:134) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:121) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:85) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:45) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:116) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:85) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
... 8 common frames omitted
```

`192.168.2.63` is my ip and mongoDB server is running, I hope someone can help me. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412850/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-using-machine-ip

Comment: For those too lazy to look, the "duplicate" suggested basically means that your "server" was never set to listen to anything other than `localhost` by default unless you told it to.