# How to access windows mongodb from WSL2

Tags: mongodb, remote-access, wsl-2, lan

I am using Mongodb on Windows where My whole project in ubuntu by WSL2. when I tried to connect my local mongodb server, I got not found error.
I tried to connect through my windows ip which is `(mongodb://192.168.x.x:27017)` but unfortunately this method is not working. even if I tried to connect this url in mongodb compass on same machine it also doesn't work.

I also have another windows Pc in same WIFI. how Can I access My Windows `mongodb` server from another PC. and How Can I access my Mongodb from wsl. please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was Got Stuck for almost half day with this problem. Atlast I found solution for this.

1. I've found out my pc local ip with `ipconfig` command in this My ip was `192.168.X.X` you should find with same format.
2. In mongodb Compass I tried to connect mongodb with my Pc ip `(mongodb://192.168.X.X:27017)` instead of default `mongodb://localhost:27017`. if though default was working but with my pc IP? that wasn't warking for me.
3. I found a answer on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413175/15379448). so according to answer I have edited `C:/Program Files/Mongodb/Sever/$VERSION/bin/mongod.cfg` this file in Admin mode. and

```
# network interfaces
net:
 port: 27017
 bindIp: 0.0.0.0 # default was 127.0.0.1
```

now My mongodb is accessible from any machine in LAN (local are network)

thank you.